# Unable to run an .exe file

Tags: 16.04, windows, wine, winetricks

I am trying to run an exe file on Ubuntu 16.04
I have installed wine and winetricks
I am using this command

```
wine64 OpenfaceOffline.exe
```

I am in super user mode
and the exe is of 64 bit

but for some reason it is giving me this error

> err:process:start_process L"Z:\home\osboxes\.wine\drive_c\Program Files\Desktop Emotion Detect\OpenFace_2.0.5_win_x64\OpenFace_2.0.5_win_x64\OpenFaceOffline.exe" doesn't have an entry point, it cannot be executed

by the look of it, it is an entry point error 
guide me how to resolve it

Comment: this thing here? https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace seems like you can compile it and run it for linux. would you like to do that instead of trying to run a windows compilation via wine?

Comment: actually I want to run one of its exe file which is OpenfaceOffline.exe

Comment: as I specified, you can have the linux equivalent : `OpenfaceOffline.sh` or `OpenfaceOffline` short. it is just a sub-branch : https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/tree/master/gui/OpenFaceOffline, use  this:  https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/wiki/Unix-Installation

Comment: it is not a .sh extension file it is an .exe file please have a close look

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. It is not advisable to run the exe file under wine, since there are extensive install instructions for ubuntu. Stick to these: https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/wiki/Unix-Installation

Answer (score 0):

You may simply run OpenfaceOffline for linux instead :

1. https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/archive/master.zip
2. `unzip ~/Downloads/OpenFace-master.zip`
3. `cd ~/OpenFace-master`
4. `chmod +x download_models.sh install.sh`
5. `./download_models.sh`
6. `./install.sh`

(you'll have to type in your password and be patient, it takes a long while you'll also have to type in "y" to accept installation of dependencies after a long while.)

7. run it with `./build/bin/FaceLandmarkVid -f "samples/changeLighting.wmv" -f "samples/2015-10-15-15-14.avi"`

works brilliant for me.

Comment: as the installation part take a while to finish. I have try the command number 7 but it gives me an error I am putting the error in my next 2 comment since it is a little longer error so please check it out

Comment: Reading the landmark detector/tracker from: ./build/bin/model/main_ceclm_general.txt
Reading the landmark detector module from: ./build/bin/model/cen_general.txt
Reading the PDM module from: ./build/bin/model/pdms/In-the-wild_aligned_PDM_68.txt....Done
Reading the Triangulations module from: ./build/bin/model/tris_68.txt....Done
Reading the intensity CEN patch experts from: ./build/bin/model/patch_experts/cen_patches_0.25_of.dat....Could not find CEN patch experts, for instructions of how to download them, see https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/wiki/Model-download

Comment: ERROR: Could not load the landmark detector